# Category subcategory pass through JSON PHP

Tags: php, android, json

I want to pass a json array in form of

```
category_list: [
                {category_name: ,
                 category_id: , 
                       subcategory_list: [
                                   {subcategory_name: ,
                                    subcategory_id: ,
                                                        subsubcategory_list:[
                                                        {subsubcategory_name: ,
                                                        subsubcategory_id: ,
                                                        subsubcategory_image: , },
                                                        ]
                                   },
                                 ]
                     }
                ]
```

the php code i am using is

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","abc","");
mysql_select_db("test");

$rows=mysql("SELECT categoryid FROM category");
while($numrows=mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
$numcatid[]=$numrows;
 for(i=0;i<=count($numcatid[]);i++)
{
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE categoryid = $numrows");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;
    json_encode($output[]);
}
}
$arrayofarray[]=$output[];
json_encode($arrayofarray[]);

mysql_close();
?>
```

please correct the php code

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:
Remove all the `json_encode` calls apart from the very last, it will jsonify a multidimensional array just fine alone.

Also:
`$arrayofarray = $output`
`json_encode($arrayofarray);`

I've removed the extraneous `[]`, not sure if that was causing your issue but I don't know what those queries are returning so.. worth a go.

You use `[]` to say "add something to the end of this array", it's not like a list reference in C-sharp (or wherever)